# how do i send notification to all mobile devices when i post a new content in Drupal? also Laravel is my Authentication back-end

Tags: laravel, drupal, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Laravel for authentication and druapl for content management, and now using firebase for notification to mobile devices... how do i send notification to all mobile devices when i post a new content in druapl?
this is my send function in Laravel

```
public function sendNotification($device_token, $message)
    {
        
        
        $SERVER_API_KEY = 'myKey';
  
        $data = [
            "to" => $device_token, // for single device id
            "notification" => $message
        ];
        $dataString = json_encode($data);

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=' . $SERVER_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ];
    
        $ch = curl_init();
      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
               
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
      
        curl_close($ch);
      
        return $response;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get token id from each user device and send notification via their device token as an array.
Add a new table named devices has user_id and device_token as columns then each new user open your application his device token will be sent to your server then you should save received token as new record to devices table.

Comment: thank you. I am gonna follow this idea. One more thing! there is a table called 'personal_access_tokens' which stores the tokens against device name. what is use of this? is this related to FCM notification or like you said, we have to create a new table to store the tokens sent from mobile device?

Comment: You should create device tokens table from scratch.

Comment: Thank you very much....